# Difference between Update Manager and apt-get dist-upgrade

Tags: apt, update-manager

Is the Update Manager (or Software Updater) the frontend of apt-get dist-upgrade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly, `Update Manager`, `Software Centre` and the apt suite (`apt-get` and `apt-cache`) are all front-ends to `dpkg` so anything that can be done with one can done with the others, but it is usually much easier to use the GUI tools which will also handle editing the config files automaically.

Note that the only `dpkg` command that most people use directly is `dpkg --configure -a` to fix things up when an install fails.

Answer (score 6):

Update-manager is essentially a GUI frontend for `apt`, which includes `apt-get update`, `upgrade`, and `dist-upgrade` functionality.  Using the Update Manager is more convenient than using `apt-get dist-upgrade`, because using this command to upgrade to a new version of your distribution requires the modification of configuration files.  There is less room for error using the Update Manager than using `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

`do-release-upgrade` is a command line tool similar to the Update Manager, which also does not require modification of apt configuration files.

Comment: To correct a common misconception: `apt-get dist-upgrade` is not just for upgrading to a new version of ubuntu (it is poorly named).  `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade` is a reasonable way to apply day-to-day package updates from the command line and will not upgrade to a new version of ubuntu.  For most purposes there is no reason to use `apt-get upgrade` at all.

Answer (score 4):

In a way yes. However the Update Manager combines a lot of `apt-get` commands that may depend on your update settings.

[image: Update Settings]

You can have a better understanding of `apt-get` options if you read the [AptGet/Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto).Then you can figure out which GUI option correspond to which `apt-get` command.