# Software updater shows updates but not apt-get

Tags: apt, upgrade, update-manager

This popped up:

[image: software updater]

When I run apt-get in a terminal, however, I get:

```
    sudo apt-get dist-upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

    sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

What's going on? Why does software updater show updates not installable through the command line?

Comment: You may wish to start with `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @ElderGeek I did, just didn't include it in the post.

Comment: There was a recent update to apt. What happens if you apply the updates in software updater?

Comment: @ElderGeek I didn't want to try before understanding what was going on. I've been burned too many times.

Comment: I just tried to upgrade one package shown by itself and failed. `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser; ...; chromium-browser is already the newest version.`

Comment: You may find this useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/191519/mismatch-of-packages-to-be-updated-between-update-manager-gui-and-apt-getcli?rq=1#

Comment: @ElderGeek I saw that, and in fact I tried both dist-upgrade and upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

If apt-get dist-upgrade doesn't work try one of the following until the problem resolves itself:

`apt-get upgrade -f`         # continue upgrade even after error

**or**

`apt-get dist-upgrade -f`    # continue dist-upgrade even after error

source: http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/debianproblem.htm

Comment: Both say the same as without the `-f` flag.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/179807/difference-between-update-manager-and-apt-get-dist-upgrade?rq=1 specifically `dpkg --configure -a`