# Where does 20.04 Software Updater keep log file?

Tags: update-manager, log

Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS current, maintained through `Software Updater` GUI application.  Where does Software Update keep log files of the actual activity and results of each time it runs?  If these are just the log files of child processes it forks/execs (e.g., `apt` or some incantation thereof), a complete list of locations and generic file names would be appreciated (e.g., foobar-log-xxxxx, muck-log-yyyyy, etc., where xxxxx, yyyyy, etc., are the specific run identifiers associated with each child process that actually is generating log files).  There appears to be no answer to this subject on Ask Ubuntu that is anywhere near current.

Answer (score 3):

For files installed using the apt system, you can examine `/var/log/apt/history.log`  - you may also find older log files in the directory `/var/log/apt`

Comment: Your answer applies to a manual invocation of apt; I appreciate your answer, but I already knew that.  What of ```Software Updater```?  Is it just an update-aware GUI front end for apt -- that internally "forks and execs" the apt system to do the actual "work"?

Comment: @YashaKarant Please review [https://askubuntu.com/questions/179807/difference-between-update-manager-and-apt-get-dist-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179807/difference-between-update-manager-and-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Comment: Thank you -- the short answer is that ```Software Update Manager``` (SUM) is a GUI front end for the ```apt``` "family" that is a front end for ```dpkg```.   Earlier, redundant copies of kernels and kernel "boot" files were displayed by ```Synaptic Package Manager```  (SPM) after hunting.  Does SPM interact properly with SUM such that if SPM "removes" or installs "something", SUM et al. also will be aware of the changes?

Comment: @YashaKarant I have not had to use Synaptic (yet) - my needs are fairly simple, and I'm quite comfortable with apt.  I often see synaptic recommended when someone has gotten into a situation where apt cannot resolve packages correctly, and I am told synaptic is able to fix situations that would otherwise involve a deeper understanding of apt, or direct use of dpkg.  Not that I'm really good (I'm not) but I'm pretty comfortable with medium usage of apt, and light usage of dpkg.